# Python - Can I color strings that are inside a list?

Tags: python, list, random, colors

Fist of all I would like to clarify that at the time of writing this I'm a complete newbie to Python and programming in general, I've only picked up Python yesterday.

I'm learning the language while working on a personal proyect.

My code takes numbers from 1 to 5, runs them through a random.choices Method and weighs them, then returns a random list that would look like this:

[2,1,4,5,2] Let's call this list **xs**

Each of those numbers has a list of strings asociated to them, let's call them "xsn"

So 1 has xs1 = ['1stringA','1stringB',...,'1stringZ'], same with 2,3,4 and 5

I then run **xs** through this code

```
while True:
    for i in range(5):
        if xs[i] == 1:
            xs[i] = (random.choice(xs1))
        if xs[i] == 2:
            xs[i] = (random.choice(xs2))
        if xs[i] == 3:
            xs[i] = (random.choice(xs3))    [Tips on how to improve this code are also accepted and apreciated]
        if xs[i] == 4:
            xs[i] = (random.choice(xs4))
        if xs[i] == 5:
            xs[i] = (random.choice(xs5))
    print(xs)
```

This will give me a modified **xs** list that, instead of numbers from 1 to 5, has strings. So if the last list was

[2,1,4,5,2]

The new **xs** list would be

['2stringA','1stringA','4stringA','5stringA','2stringB']

What I want is for each number to also have it's own asociated color, so '2stringA' and '2stringB' would be Green, '1stringA' would be White and so on.

Any ideas on how to make this happen? Sorry for writing such a long post, as I get better I hope I can sumarise my questions in a more condensed manner.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Basically, having started to learn Python just yesterday means you should be reading tutorials, not asking people to give you code. Otherwise, your project will be written by other people, and this isn't the place for that.

Comment: Yeah, I think you got the right idea, I'll look at some tutorials tomorrow and educate myself.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understood correctly but try this code

```
from colorama import Fore

while True:
    for i in range(5):
        if xs[i] == i:
            xs[i] = Fore.GREEN + random.choice(xs + i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did not work but gave me some ideas on what I should be looking at, much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear.
I'm going to assume that you want to print out the code in different colors.
There are various libraries for that, such as [termcolor](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/),  [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) and [colored](https://gitlab.com/dslackw/colored)

Also, you could create a nested list (`xsn = [[], xs1, xs2, xs3, etc]`), or a dictionary (`xsn = {1: xs1, 2: xs3, etc etc}`), so you'd have something like `xs[i] = random.choice(xsn[i])` instead of `if xs[i]: do something` blocks,

You could also do something like [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/), but since you say you started with python yesterday, that might not be the best idea.
But if you do decide to use it, it'd look something like `new_xs = [random.choice(xsn[i]) for i in xs]`

Comment: "Your question isn't really clear" then don't answer it. Ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how my question is not that clear, still, I'll look into the tools you mentioned and see how I can implement them. Thanks for the tips too :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, looks like this now, if anyone is interested in knowing how I did it leave a reply, but I'm quite happy with how it ended up :^)

[If any if you play TFT you might guess what I'm doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCCrA.png)